# Having exception. Spring 3 with Spring Tool Suite, Tomcat 7 and Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat7

I am new to Spring 3. I newly installed Eclipse Indigo, Spring Tool Suite.
Using Spring Tool Suite "Spring Template --> Spring MVC project". I created a Hello world application.

When running the application. It gives a exception.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/index_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used in the signature
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:31)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:181)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:370)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

What is wrong with the set up

Comment: Bozho is right, that the problem is that you have a second el-api.jar. But if it is defined with `<scope>provided</scope>` the dependency must come from somewhere else. But to verify that, I would recommend that you build the application by maven and then deploy the war by hand (without IDE). If the exception is not gone, check if some other dependency that is not provided depends on `el-api.jar` (STS, pom.xml, Dependency Hierarchy tab)

Comment: Bozho i tried to enable m2e-wtp setup from your guidance. But my Eclipse got hanged. So tried with Ralph choice. Deployed the WAR file manually in Tomcat and tried it. The error Disappeared. Note: I had to remove the <Dependency> tag of el-api.jar in pom.xml.

Comment: does the WAR worked with el-api and scope provided?

Answer (score 1):

Remove any `el-api.jar` from `WEB-INF/lib`

If you are running from within the IDE, you should have the `el-api.jar` with `provided` scope at most. Even with that it may still fail, because the IDE sometimes doesn't take into account the scope. I think the [m2e-wtp](http://planet.jboss.org/post/m2e_clipse_wtp_0_13_0_new_noteworthy) plugin should fix it.

Comment: There is no el-api.jar in WEB-INF/lib directory. I have not added anything to the default setup given by the MVC Structure.

Comment: what are the contents of your WEB-INF/lib ? (or, if you are deploying through the IDE - do you have that jar in your list of dependencies)

Comment: Yes in pom.xml i have given Dependency **`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId> 
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>2.2</version>
 </dependency>`**. Also my WEB-INF/lib is empty.

Comment: @Ezhil - this is a common problem with IDEs - they don't take into account the "provided" scope and copy the jar. see my update

Comment: @Bozho: sorry but in this case it is not the IDE, sts with M2Eclipse handle the provieded scope correct.

Comment: @Ralph - does it? My eclipse with m2e doesn't. It does only when there is the m2e-wtp plugin.

Comment: @Ezhil - clean your tomcat, just in case

Comment: @Bozho m2e is evil in many ways. I have reverted to m2eclipse again.

Answer (score 1):

it's because the template is created for Tomcat 6.0 with JSP 2.1 and Tomcat 7.0 works with JSP 2.2.
As you can see in this page:
http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html.

I try to change the jsp jar for a 2.2 in the pom.xml and add the el-api 2.2. but it's not enought. I don't find the final problem.

Finally I choose to use the tomcat 6.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by editing the POM, changing the jsp-api version from 2.1 to 2.2

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>  <!-- 2.1 for Tomcat 6, 2.2 for Tomcat 7 -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```